# How to pass a filename as a string to awk to parse for destination

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, ksh, tcsh

## TASK

I am trying to pass a pathname/filename to awk in order to take advantage of its field seperator functionality. I want to parse a pathname/filename to see if it is within a user directory in a system. Example paths:

Absolute Paths:

```
/home/students/username               # VALID
/home/staff/username                  # VALID
/home/students/username/anythingElse  # VALID
/home/staff/username/anythingElse     # VALID
/home/notAccountStorage/anythingElse  # INVALID
```

Relative Paths (For Exmaple, where the pwd/current is /home/student/user/courseFiles):

```
../                                       # VALID /home/student/user
../otherDir                               # VALID /home/student/user/other
../.                                      # VALID /home/student/user
../..                                     # INVALID /home/student
../../otherDir                            # INVALID /home/student/otherDir
```

## CODE

My thoughts were to check if the string begins with a '/' then process for absolute path, else process for relative path.

AWK code along the lines of:

```
awk -F="/" '    BEGIN { directoryAccentCount=0                                                                  \
                        isValid=$FALSE;                                                                         \
                }                                                                                               \
                {                                                                                               \
                        # If the string starts with a "/", path is absolute                                     \
                        if ( $0 ~ /^\// ) {                                                                     \
                                # If either Student/Staff && Number of Fields must be great than 2              \
                                if ( ($2 == "student" || $2 == "staff") && NF > 2 ) isValid=$TRUE               \
                        } else {                                                                                \
                        # Path is relative                                                                      \
                                for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {                                                     \
                                        # Count how many directories the User wants to ASCEND towards ROOT      \
                                        if ( $i ~ /\.\./ ) { directoryAccentCount++ }                           \
                                        # If the difference between the Number of Fields and                    \
                                        # the Accent Count is greater than 2, isValid=$TRUE                     \
                                        difference=(NF - $directoryAccentCount)                                 \
                                        if ( $difference > 2 ) isValid=$TRUE                                    \
                        }                                                                                       \
                }                                                                                               \
                END { print $0 ":" $isValid }' << HERE $providedPath
HERE
```

## ERROR

I have tried variations of the above code, but awk keeps attempting to follow the file path, open the file, and process the file's text. I want to process the path itself.

awk: fatal: file `noCopyDir1' is a directory

Comment: `HERE $provicdedPath HERE` need to be on 3 separate lines. That should work, but not a traditional approach. `echo "$providedPATH" | awk -f .... ` might be better. Then  you can `exit 0` if OK, and `exit 1` (or other) to indicate a problem. Good luck.

Comment: You are vastly confusing awk and shell. They are separate tools with their very own syntax and purpose. Get and read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins ASAP and until you have don't try to use awk as you currently fundamentally misunderstand it.

Comment: @Ed Morton - I have found an answer to this solution using awk, which I am calling inside a shell script.

Comment: Then you have found the wrong "solution" as this is NOT a problem best solved with awk. awk is a tool for manipulating text. That's all. You can mangle awk to do other things just like you can mangle shell to manipulate text but in both cases you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @Ed Morton - I am open to constructive suggestions for better tools for the task I am trying to achieve. My answer below may clarify what I was trying to achieve. Reading an entire book is not real an option with my projects time constraints.

Comment: You'd only have to read the first couple of introductory chapters to understand how far off the rails your above script is. I'm not exaggerating - you really should get some basic awk info before trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

your solution is too complicated. you can do it within one line in bash. there could be solution shorter than mine:

```
[ -d "$(readlink -f $YOUR_PATH | awk -F/ '$2 == "home" && $3 != "" {print "/"$2"/"$3}')" ]
```

explanation:

```
readlink -f $YOUR_PATH
```

this converts whatever path to a absolute one.

```
awk -F/ '$2 == "home" && $3 != "" {print "/"$2"/"$3}'
```

since the path is absolute already, so i can directly extract the first two path out, but restrict it's under home folder and it's under some subfolder too.

then just check to see if it's a folder.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it's not clear from your question but it sounds like you just want to check if a path given in a file exists or not. That would be:

```
while IFS= read -r path
do
    [[ -e "$path" ]] && echo "valid" || echo "invalid"
done < file
```

Comment: More rigid validation required, but yes I do use this a few logical steps above the later use of awk

Comment: If I had more time I would re-write the question as the first two answers posted where not even close to the solution I was looking for. Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) instead of [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). It can handle paths easily with `Cwd` and `File::stat` modules, like:

```
perl -mCwd=realpath -MFile::stat -E '
    $p = realpath($ARGV[0]); 
    say $p =~ m{\A/home/} && stat($p) ? q|VALID| : q|INVALID|' 
'../../otherDir'
```

It gets absolute path, checks that it is a `home` directory and it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified logic to determine directory ascent/decent only in the case of relative paths. The awk script takes advantage of looping through the fields one by one and returns a negative value when moving towards the root and a positive value when moving away from root.

```
 # Check that the distance from a User Directory
                set movingDistance = `echo $argPath | awk -F'/' 'BEGIN{                                 \
                        distanceMoved=0                                                                 \
                }                                                                                       \
                {                                                                                       \
                        for ( i=1; i<NF; i++ ) {                                                        \
                                if ( $i ~ /\.\./ ) {                                                    \
                                        distanceMoved--                                                 \
                                } else {                                                                \
                                        distanceMoved++                                                 \
                                }                                                                       \
                        }                                                                               \
                }                                                                                       \
                END {                                                                                   \
                        print distanceMoved                                                             \
                }'`
```

This is an essential step in determining whether a file path advances outside of user accounts in a system or remains within a user directory, which is how I am applying the script, however, it can be used in many other cases.

Comment: It's not clear at all what the above is intended to do. If you just want awk to count how many `/`s are in an input stream that'd be `awk '{print gsub(/\//,"&")}'` but why test for `..` and how would you handle `dir//dir2`? It's also fundamentally flawed in the use of the `distanceMoved` variable init and printing. We can't tell what it is you want to do by reading scripts that don't do what you want to do - I highly recommend you post a new, much clearer question.